# Implementing Sound Notifications for Database Notifications in Laravel Filament v3

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-10, laravel-filament

I'm currently working on a project using Laravel Filament v3, and I want to implement a feature where a sound plays when a database notification is received. I've successfully set up database notifications using Filament's built-in features, but I'm unsure about how to trigger a sound when a notification is received.

I've searched for solutions online but haven't found a clear, up-to-date guide specifically for Laravel Filament v3. Could someone provide guidance on how to achieve this sound notification feature in Laravel Filament v3?

Here's what I've done so far:

I've set up database notifications for my application.
I have a notification system that works with the Laravel notification system, and I can send notifications to users.
What I'm missing is the ability to play a sound when a notification is received. I'd like to know how to integrate this audio notification feature into my Laravel Filament v3 project.

Any code examples or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step1: Create Javascript function for playing sound:

```
function playNotificationSound() {
    const audio = new Audio('/path/to/notification-sound.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

Replace /path/to/notification-sound.mp3 with the actual path to your sound file.

step2:Integrate the JavaScript Function in Your Laravel Filament Project

```
<script>
    function playNotificationSound() {
        const audio = new Audio('/path/to/notification-sound.mp3');
        audio.play();
    }
</script>
```

stpe3:To play the notification sound when a database notification is received, you'll need to call the playNotificationSound()

```
 @if(session('notification'))
        <div class="notification">
            {{ session('notification') }}
            <script>
                playNotificationSound();
            </script>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, as per your code, it should work perfectly But In filament which File do I need to place this code. cause in filament there are no published layout files shown, what I have found is in vendor directory containing the Application layout. I already tried as per the filament documentation where I have to create a one custom layout file But it won't work.